# How to override ToString() in an SRTP class

Tags: f#

I am having issues creating a generic math class (here as very tiny example code a class of type Vector) that, however, is not limited to one single numerical data type for its values, but instead uses `^F` as **static resolved type parameter**, and I expect it to be whatever the user uses to instanciate the class, such as `int` but also `BigRational` or `MyCustomNumber`, as long as it adheres to the constraints.

```
type Vector< ^F> (_values : ^F []) =
    let values = _values
    member inline __.Dimension = Array.length values
    member inline __.Item with get i = values.[i + 1]
    static member inline ( * ) (a: Vector< ^F>) (scalar: ^F) =
        Vector< ^F>(Array.init (a.Dimension) (fun i -> values.[i] * scalar)
    override inline __.ToString() = "{" + (values.ToString()) + "}" // <--- problem-line
```

My problem now with this code is, that I still don't know how to properly override the `Object.ToString()` method (same for how to implement IComparable, which I believe I could fix the same way).

Is this actually even possible?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

- Do not annotate the arithmetic operator's arguments with a type parameter, they will be inferred alright
- Pass the arguments of the arithmetic operator as a tuple
- Close the parenthesis in the implementation of the arithmetic operator
- Replace the `let`-bound value `values` by a property

```
type Vector<'F> (_values : 'F[]) =
    member val Values = _values
    member inline me.Dimension = Array.length me.Values
    member inline me.Item with get i = me.Values.[i + 1]
    static member inline ( * ) (a: Vector<_>, scalar) =
        Vector<_>(Array.init (a.Dimension) (fun i -> a.Values.[i] * scalar))
    override me.ToString() = "{" + (me.Values.ToString()) + "}"
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your reply. If I'm not mistaken, `'F` is a generic (runtime checked types), in contrast to `^F` which would be compile-time checked. Out of curiosity - what's the whole point of SRTP then, if I can't use it? -- OTOH, I'll try out your proposal ASAP. Many thanks! :)